# Can the memory of an arrow::MemoryMappedFile be accessed directly?

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, pyarrow

To Developers,
I am using a arrow::MemoryMappedFile and instead of making a copy of the data, I  would like to access it directly.
Is there a way to access this data in memory?

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can access its memory directly by calling [`MemoryMappedFile::ReadAt`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c9c7f9c09aa1f5bf17b53704c94ae39888f6fce7/cpp/src/arrow/io/file.h#L207). This will return a `std::shared_ptr<Buffer>` that references the memory of the file. This involves no copy of the data. When you specify `position = 0` and `nbytes = <size of file>` you will the whole memory region.